# which class or widget to use a better responsive layout in the flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This class or widget is useful to create a responsive layout.

AspectRatio
CustomSingleChildLayout,
CustomMultiChildLayout,
FittedBox,
FractionallySizedBox,
LayoutBuilder,
MediaQuery,
MediaQueryData,
OrientationBuilder.

Which is to use the better responsive layout.

Comment: It all depends on your use case.

Comment: nice question i'll add a bounty on it  after two days

Answer (score 2):

iDecode already told you that it all depends on what you need. here take a look at official documentation, https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout.
And here is my advice

- Use row when you need Horizontal layout
- Use column when you need Vertical layout
- Use singleChildScrollView when you need scrolling layout
- Use either GridView or listView when you need repetitive view
- Use Expanded, Flexible, Limitedbox, flexiblebox for adjusting the size of the widget

Answer (score 0):

Mine favourite : Rows for Horizontal, Column for vertical, Scrollview for Extra data exist in the page or UI not fitted in the screen, ListView for TableView UI etc

For best fitting layout: IS Expanded, AspectRatio